# Linear Least Squares In Matrix Form

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, least-squares

if we are given a set of points $\{(x_i,y_i)\}$ and we are looking to fit a straight line $ax+b$ "as close" to the points as possible we are building a set of equations.

One way is to take the partial derivatives with respect to $a,b$ and find the min.

On the matrix form we multiply by $A^T$ when $A$ is entries of $1,x,x^2,..$ why is it smilier to finding the min using derivative?

Comment: Smilier ? What does it mean?

Comment: Similar, I guess ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some [cookbook about matrix and vector calculus](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) on the internet where we can derive $${\bf x_o}=\min_{\bf x}\{\|{\bf Ax-b}\|_2^2\}$$
by

1. Differentiating the expression
   $$\|{\bf Ax-b}\|_2^2=({\bf Ax-b})^T({\bf Ax-b})$$
   (With respect to $\bf x$)
2. Setting this derivative to zero.
3. Solving for $\bf x$

Doing these steps is a good exercise.

Comment: Wow this great, must be bookmarked.

Comment: I need to derive $(Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$ is deriving matrices-by-vectors?

Comment: You can multiply it together and differentiate each resulting term with help of the book.